# How to apply conditional member visibility in F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

.NET languages in general are not meta-programming friendly, but C# at least has #define pragma directly in code which can be used with if statement or ConditionalAttribute.

Looking for any possibility to manage member visibility on runtime in F#.

In particular I want to stop editor to autocomplete several properties depending on configuration from json or other runtime values.

For example if I have F# record type `Sample = {A:string;B:string;C:string}`, sometimes I want to hide from completion A or C, B and C etc

The visibility should change on some context switch like cell switch in Jupyter Notebook or Rest API result. But without any libraries recompilation.

Is this something `TypeProvider` can do?

Update:
In  'interactive' context I always have a list which properties I want to have visible for autocompletion like [ "A" ;"C"] or ["B" ;"C" ].
The ideal solution would be to mark my record fields with attribute [<"A" >] and compiler tools will make it visible only if my runtime list contains "A".

Comment: What about using interfaces ? You cast to a certain interface in a certain context, you got completion corresponding to the interface.

Comment: Well, it sounds like a possible easy solution but for simplicity I mentioned only A B C. In fact it will be dozens of fields plus dozens of nested fields which makes casting not possible to maintain.

Comment: So because of this you want to use configuration files, on which is based the static analysis (including type inference and partial type inference) ? This analysis can also depend on runtime objects (state, types, values). In the case of static analysis, it sounds like an editor feature, in the case of dynamic, sounds like to fall in the scope of reflection functions.

Comment: Can you give a bit more background here? Is the idea that F# programmer writing code in some editor will see a different version of library based on some runtime configuration?